# What's bacon good for?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

In *Plants vs. Zombies*, Crazy Dave has bacon for sale.  Its description is "Mmmmmmm... Delicious!".  I've bought one or two slices of bacon, but I've never noticed a benefit.  What's the bacon good for?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Bacon has no purpose but to make Crazy Dave say, "Mmmmmmm... Delicious!"

It has no in game function.

Source: [Plants vs Zombies wikia](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Bacon)

Comment: That's what I buy it for as well!

Answer (score 0):

It's just a waste of money. All it does is make Crazy Dave say: "Mmmmm! Delicious!"

Believe me, I bought probably over 1,000,000 pieces, because I thought it would do something, but it never did ._.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Arqade!  Just as a heads-up: you've likely been downvoted because you don't add any new information-you just say what's already here in the other answer.